# deleting image heavy custom uitableviewcells

Tags: iphone, objective-c, memory, uitableview

I have a table which is made from custom UITableViewCells which contains downloaded images.

Ive found the app crashes after too many images are displayed. How can best stop this? I don't mind deleting the first images, but don't know of the best way to do it.

**EDIT**

How do I write the images to the device for caching?

Comment: @daidai : I do'nt think you application is crashing because of displaying too many images , plz share the crash log with us..

Comment: @daidai: do you mean application crashes when we scroll tableView?

Comment: Sounds like a memory issue to me, are you dequeuing your cells? Are you release any old image that are in memory? Do you write the images to the device for caching?

Comment: I believe it is a memory issue as I'm getting Received memory warning. Level=1 and Received memory warning. Level=2. This is the question, how do I deal with having memory warnings?

Comment: please post cellForRowAtIndexPath: method code

Comment: I have edited my original question

Comment: @daidai, besure to call release on any images that you have alloc init. (or any NSData object that is allo/init).

Answer (score 0):

Post your cellForRowAtIndexPath code. Sounds like you have a problem there. If you're certain you do not, then when you receive the memory warning, release any objects you do not need, and can easily be loaded again if required. These objects may be in other ViewControllers not on screen or ImageView objects already displayed.

Best we can do unless you post code.

Or read Apple's Memory Management Guide.